# How to take picture with mjpg_streamer

Tags: linux, mjpeg, openwrt, command-line-interface

Helooo I'm trying to take picture from command line with mjpg streamer and save the result to some folder. I try this:

```
mjpg_streamer --input "input_uvc.so --device /dev/video0" --output "output_file.so --folder /result/"
```

And Error result:

MJPG Streamer Version: svn rev: exported

i: Using V4L2 device.: /dev/video0

i: Desired Resolution: 640 x 480

i: Frames Per Second.: 5

i: Format............: MJPEG

Unable to set format: 1196444237 res: 640x480
 Init v4L2 failed !! exit fatal

i: init_VideoIn failed

Somebody please help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Run MJPGSTREAMER**

```
mjpg_streamer -i "input_uvc.so -d /dev/video0 -r 320x240 -y"  -o "output_http.so -p 8080 -b
```

**Get Picture**

```
wget http://192.168.1.1:8080/?action=snapshot -O output.jpg
```

Comment: makasih bro, udah ketemu sama persis kayak yang ini. cuma MJPG streamer gk perlu dijalanin lagi. :)

Answer (score 0):

When getting `Unable to set format: 1196444237 res: 640x480 Init v4L2 failed !! exit fatal`

Make sure nobody else is using your device (`/dev/device0`).

This solved me the issue :)